# How can I add a rectangle in BorderLayout.SOUTH?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, paintcomponent

I am trying to add a thing like [this](https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/sound-bar-chart-colorful-stereo-who-like-to-listen-to-music-55216476.jpg) in my music player application in swing.

I tried to add a rectangle to `BorderLayout.SOUTH`, but it never appeared on screen. Here is *what* I did:

```
public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.fillRect(200,200,200,200);

    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        MyDrawPanel a = new MyDrawPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.SOUTH,a);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(1000,1000);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

I just did not try 200,200,200,200, but I tried a lot of values, even with the help of a *for* loop, but it never appeared on screen. If I used `CENTER` instead of `SOUTH` it appeared. I read the documentation to check how `fillRect` works, but it simply said it added x+width and y+height. The point `(0,0)` is the top left corner. I checked that by adding a rectangle to `CENTER` layout. How cam I do it?

I did not share the output, because it was just a blank screen.

Comment: I have added rectangle to JPanel and added JPanel to JFrame

Comment: You need to set a `LayoutManager` to the frame's `ContentPane`, ie `frame.getContentPane().setLayoutManager(new BorderLayout())`, before adding the draw panel.

Comment: Border layout is by default for JFrame, so there is no need to add it

Comment: A custom painted component needs to return a preferred size big enough to display what it renders, as a hint to the layout manager. Sidebar: Always call the `super` method first, when overriding a paint method. Sidebar 2: replace `frame.setSize(1000,1000);` with `frame.pack();` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought this might make a quick little project.  Here's the level meter I came up with.

[image: Level Meter GUI]

The important parts are the `DrawingPanel` and the `LevelMeterModel`.  The `DrawingPanel` takes the information from the `LevelMeterModel` and paints the bars on a `JPanel`.

The `LevelMeterModel` is an int array of levels, a minimum level, and a maximum level.  The maximum level could be calculated, but I assumed music has a certain volume and frequency range.

The `JFrame` holds the `DrawingPanel`.  A Swing `Timer` varies the levels somewhat randomly.  The random numbers are in a small range so the bar heights don't change abruptly.

Here's the complete runnable code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class LevelMeterGUI implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new LevelMeterGUI());
    }
    
    private final DrawingPanel drawingPanel;
    
    private final LevelMeterModel model;
    
    public LevelMeterGUI() {
        this.model = new LevelMeterModel();
        this.drawingPanel = new DrawingPanel(model);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Level Meter GUI");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        frame.add(drawingPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        System.out.println("Frame size: " + frame.getSize());
        
        Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                model.setRandomLevels();
                drawingPanel.repaint();
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }
    
    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        
        private final int drawingWidth, drawingHeight, margin, rows;
        
        private final Dimension barDimension;
        
        private final LevelMeterModel model;
        
        public DrawingPanel(LevelMeterModel model) {
            this.model = model;
            this.margin = 10;
            this.rows = 20;
            this.barDimension = new Dimension(50, 10);
            
            int columns = model.getLevels().length;
            drawingWidth = columns * barDimension.width + (columns + 1) * margin;
            drawingHeight = rows * barDimension.height + (rows + 1) * margin;
            
            this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(drawingWidth, drawingHeight));
        }
        
        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            
            int maximum = model.getMaximumLevel();
            double increment = (double) maximum / rows;
            
            int peak = rows * 75 / 100;
            int x = margin;
            for (int level : model.getLevels()) {
                int steps = (int) Math.round((double) level / increment);
                int y = drawingHeight - margin - barDimension.height;
                for (int index = 0; index < steps; index++) {
                    if (index < peak) {
                        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                    } else {
                        g.setColor(Color.RED);
                    }
                    g.fillRect(x, y, barDimension.width, barDimension.height);
                    y = y - margin - barDimension.height;
                }
                x += margin + barDimension.width;
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    public class LevelMeterModel {
        
        private final int minimumLevel, maximumLevel;
        
        private int[] levels;
        
        private final Random random;
        
        public LevelMeterModel() {
            this.minimumLevel = 100;
            this.maximumLevel = 999;
            this.levels = new int[8];
            this.random = new Random();
            setRandomLevels();
        }
        
        public void setRandomLevels() {
            for (int index = 0; index < levels.length; index++) {
                levels[index] = getRandomLevel(levels[index]);
            }
        }
        
        private int getRandomLevel(int level) {
            if (level == 0) {
                return random.nextInt(maximumLevel - minimumLevel) + minimumLevel;
            } else {
                int minimum = Math.max(level * 90 / 100, minimumLevel);
                int maximum = Math.min(level * 110 / 100, maximumLevel);
                return random.nextInt(maximum - minimum) + minimum;
            }
        }

        public int[] getLevels() {
            return levels;
        }

        public int getMinimumLevel() {
            return minimumLevel;
        }

        public int getMaximumLevel() {
            return maximumLevel;
        }
        
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The values you give to `fillRect` are wrong. The first two are the top left corner's coordinates, relative to the component you're painting in; in your case the `MyDrawPanel`. With the code you posted, this drawing area is outside of the container the panel is placed in. You want to do

```
g.fillRect(0,0,200,200);
```

A note: You usually want to call `frame.pack()` after you've finished adding all components, so it can layout itself. In your case, this results in a tiny window because the system doesn't know how large it should be. You probably want to add a method

```
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    System.out.println("getting pref size");
    return new Dimension(200, 200);
}
```

to ensure it's always large enough to draw the full rectangle.

Also, you should call `frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout())` before. You can print it out without setting it to see it is not the default. EDIT: As VGR points out, the documentation says that it is in fact a `BorderLayout`. I cannot confirm that is the case - it is in fact a `RootLayout`. That seems to behave like a `BorderLayout` though.

Comment: Your last paragraph is incorrect.  [The default layout for a content pane is always a BorderLayout.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JFrame.html)

Comment: @VGR Thats what I mentioned above, I cannot think of any coordinates for showing in south, can you help with it.

Comment: @daniu Your answer is partially correct, I will give you that but I apparently can't change the height of the rectangle (I can change width) have any solution for that?

Comment: @VGR that is weird. I went into the rabbit hole of the source code, and per default, `JFrame` creates a `JRootPane` which uses a `RootLayout`, but that doesn't inherit from `BorderLayout`. It may behave like one, but IIUC, the documentation as such is not correct.

Comment: @ThunderKnight I don't see how my answer is not entirely correct. Your question was how to get the rectangle to appear in SOUTH, and I answered that. How to get it to resize was never part of the question, so I don't see how I even could have answered that. It is, in fact, a separate question and you should open a new one for that.

Comment: @daniu I did some tweaking on my own and I was able to get what I wanted, of course your answer is helpful and almost correct ( just the border layout, which is default for jframe). Thanks for your help, its this community only that helps a lot, thanks again man.

Comment: @daniu The JFrame’s content is a JRootPane, but we are not talking about the layout of the rootPane or the JFrame.  We are talking about the layout of the contentPane which is inside the rootPane.